# What is the language recognized by the following deterministic finite-state automaton?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

[image]

Is the answer:

```
{w : w ∈ {0*,1*} and w contains at least 3 zero}
```

correct?

Comment: The language of all strings using the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ is more properly denoted as $(0|1)^{*}$. Other than that, looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you meant the correct thing, but you should write

$$\{w \in \{0,1\}^* \space | \space w \text{ contains at least 3 0's}\}.$$

As a regular expression, this can be expressed as (as adjan has already done)

$$1^*01^*01^*0(0|1)^*$$

Comment: Ok i see :)

Would this solution: (0 | 1)* (0 | 1)* (0 | 1)*

Be accepted too or?

Comment: (0|1)*(0|1)*(0|1)* is the same as (0|1)*

Comment: (0|1)* wouldn't be accepted or?

Comment: @TheFermat I don't think that expression would be correct since you need to have the three zeros.

Comment: This is why I posted my answer... "3 zeros" have to be expressed as a regualar expression i thought?

Comment: (0|1)* and the string must contain at least 3 0's

Would that be a allowed language?

Comment: @adjan Yes. Your expression seems correct. It's the way to say there are at least three zeros.